# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 14105: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, python-3.x

I took some books and tried to count how many times a word occurs in that book, and everything was ok until on one book  I got this:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 14105: character maps to <'undefined>

```
def couting_func(file, word):
#the function takes a file and cout how many times word occurs in that file
try:
    with open(file) as file_object:
        lines = file_object.read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("The file is missing!!!")
else: 
    words = lines.split()
    words = words.count(word)
    print(words)
```

I'm kind of newbie in coding and will be grateful if someone will explain what I did wrong... and how to get rid of this

p.s. I also tried to put another try/except block in with UnicodeDecodeError but then all just stops

Comment: Hi, can you post the stack trace? When you run the code and it generates the exception.  There are usually more printed on screen showing important information: what the exception is, where the exception is raised, etc.

Comment: That means that the file you are reading is not encoded in the encoding format your computer is trying to use. In UTF8, (one of the most common) the character \x98 is a continuation character, meaning it's only valid with a specific second character after it. You need to find the right encoding for the file, or tell python to ignore errors with `open(file, errors='ignore')`.

Comment: All books I took were from [http://www.gutenberg.org][1]


and I downloaded them in UTF-8 [img from site][2]


  [1]: http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/search/%3Fsort_order%3Ddownloads
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9M9W.jpg

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for the tip `open(file, errors='ignore')`  it works !