# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 7736: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 7736: character maps to `<undefined>`

```py
def ReadAllText(path):
    r = open(path.replace("\\x", "%"))
    text = r.read()
    r.close()
    return text
```

Someone can help me with this?

Comment: Same question without answer: [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 14105: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42771449/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x98-in-position-14105-ch)

Comment: The problem is that the file contains a character that is not defined in your system's default codepage.  If you don't know what the file's encoding is supposed to be you could guess using the information [here](https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#98).  Also, check out the character encoding [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue (million record txt file), and tried below method based on internet solutions but it DID NOT WORK ,

1. for line in open(filepath)
2. for line in open(filepath,encoding = 'utf-8')

The working solutions :

1. for line in open(filepath, encoding='windows-1252',errors='ignore')
2. for line in open(filepath,encoding = 'utf-8',error='ignore')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't solve the problem, but a workaround is to save the text file in ANSI encoding and to run the script again.

Another idea is to open the file like this:

`open(file, errors='ignore')`